# When declaring an internal table by referencing a table type, can we retain its primary key?

Tags: abap

When declaring an internal table, is it possible to retain the primary key of the referenced table type (instead of specifying its components explicitly)  ?

Comment: by table type you mean Data Dictionary table type?https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ewm900/helpdata/en/90/8d7304b1af11d194f600a0c929b3c3/content.htm?no_cache=true

Comment: @Suncatcher: yes

Comment: Hi Cutter,
No you can't.

"There are two kinds of key for internal tables - the standard key and a user-defined key.
At tables with structured row type, the standard key is formed from all character-type columns of the internal table. "

(source https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-US/fc/eb3660358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Table Type** in the ABAP Dictionary means a Type which can be used to declare an Internal Table, including its primary and secondary keys, not to be confused with a **Transparent Table** which is for defining a database table, whose ABAP considers a Structure when used for typing data objects.

**To answer your question, concerning a Table Type, the primary key is always retained and cannot be changed**. In the below code, you will see that `itab` is an internal table with same primary key as `seo_cmpkeys`, ordered by `clsname` and `cmpname`, `A` will come before `B`:

```
DATA itab TYPE seo_cmpkeys.
INSERT VALUE #( clsname = 'ZCL' cmpname = 'B' ) INTO TABLE itab.
INSERT VALUE #( clsname = 'ZCL' cmpname = 'A' ) INTO TABLE itab.
```

[image: SEO_CMPKEYS]

For a **Transparent Table**, the primary key is ignored because only its structure is considered in ABAP for declaring an internal table, so you need to declare all the key fields explicitly:

```
DATA itab TYPE SORTED TABLE OF t000 WITH UNIQUE KEY mandt.
INSERT VALUE #( mandt = '101' ) INTO TABLE itab.
INSERT VALUE #( mandt = '100' ) INTO TABLE itab.
```

[image: T000]

Comment: it's better to put answers phrased to clear answer the OP question: `no, the keys from DDIC table type is ignored when declaring itab`. Your passage is very helpful and insightful, but very ambiguously answers the OP question, and will be hard for undersanding for not so proficient ABAP learners like you. SO is not an encyclopedia, rather a how-to site